# Language parameter on Graph Search

Tags: facebook, graph

Is it possible to get status updates in a certain language (similar to the Twitter search API?).

For example, I want to be able to search for status updates containing watermelon in English.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Facebook will allow you to specify

However it's funny that you used watermellon for your search word in this question as in the API documentation has this as an example query: `All public posts: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "locale"parameter.

E.g.:  All US public posts: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&locale=en_US

Comment: Unfortunately this was a bug in the api:  
"The locale parameter only returns Facebook strings that are translatable into the specified locale, everything else stays the same. It does not filter the content returned by search by locale."  
[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294623187324442)